# Criar listas de acordo com valor de um objeto

Tags: javascript, array, objetos

Preciso criar uma nova lista (listaFiltrada) que separe as informações da "listaTeste" de acordo com o codigo de cada objeto, porém, a "listaTeste" pode conter diversos codigos diferentes.

```
const listaTeste = [
    {nome: 'x', codigo: 1, codigoBobina: 1},
    {nome: 'x', codigo: 1, codigoBobina: 2},
    {nome: 'y', codigo: 2, codigoBobina: 3}
    ];
    
    let listaFiltrada = []
```

Ou seja, nesse caso que digitei acima, eu precisaria do seguinte resultado na "listaFiltrada":

```
listaFiltrada === [
[
{nome: 'x', codigo: 1, codigoBobina: 1},
{nome: 'x', codigo: 1, codigoBobina: 2}
],
[
{nome: 'y', codigo: 2, codigoBobina: 3}
]
];
```

Ou seja "listaFiltrada" seria um array com 2 arrays de objects (neste caso).

Alguém conhece algum caminho que solucione tal problema?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: O negócio é seguinte, nós fazemos isso com as mãos amarradas nas costas. O problema é que de um tempo para cá começou aparecer uns usuários que tentam usar os site como cola ou como solucionador de tarefas de casa ou programadores for free, o que tem afastado os contribuintes de valor . Teria como [edit] a pergunta e adicionar um [mcve] mostrando uma tentativa sua de solucionar o problema junto de mensagem de erro.

Answer (score 0):

Uma das soluções é percorrer a `listaTeste` e armazenar apenas os códigos diferentes - e somente os diferentes - em um array separado.
Depois basta percorrer cada elemento desse array onde os códigos diferentes foram armazenados filtrando da `listaTeste` os itens que possuem código igual a um determinado elemento do array de códigos que está sendo percorrido e armazenando esses itens em um array temporário.
Então é só fazer o push desse array temporário na `listaFiltrada`.

Veja exemplo abaixo:

```
const listaTeste = [
  {nome: 'x', codigo: 1, codigoBobina: 1},
  {nome: 'x', codigo: 1, codigoBobina: 2},
  {nome: 'y', codigo: 2, codigoBobina: 3}
];

const codigosDiferentes = [];
const listaFiltrada = [];

// Para cada item da listaTeste...
listaTeste.forEach((item) => {
  // se o código do item não existir em codigosDiferentes...
  if (codigosDiferentes.indexOf(item.codigo) === -1)
  {
    // adiciona o código em codigosDiferentes
    codigosDiferentes.push(item.codigo);
  }
});

// Para cada código diferente...
codigosDiferentes.forEach((codigo) => {
  // filtra os itens da listaTeste que possuem código igual ao código atual e os armazena no arrayTemporario
  const arrayTemporario = listaTeste.filter((itemLista) => itemLista.codigo === codigo);

  // e insere o arrayTemporario na listaFiltrada
  listaFiltrada.push(arrayTemporario);
});
```

Esta é uma das possíveis soluções para resolver o seu problema

Comment: Boa tarde, Ana Paula ! 
Boa lógica !
Obrigado, me ajudou bastante.